# How to change 'sort glyph icon' color in DataGridView of Windows Form C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview, datagridcolumnheader

I've changed the column header color by default. Now, I want to change the 'sort glyph icon' color in DataGridView of Windows Form C# when it gets sorted:

[image]

See the above picture. The column is sorted but icon's color makes it's visibility inadequate.

Please let me know if it's color can be changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There is no property for changing color of sort icon. As an option to change it, you can handle [`CellPainting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting(v=vs.110).aspx) event and draw the cell yourself.

**Example**

```
private void dgv1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    var sortIconColor = Color.Red;
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
    {
        using (var b = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
        {
            //Draw Background
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, false);

            //Draw Text Default
            //e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);

            //Draw Text Custom
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, string.Format("{0}", e.FormattedValue),
                e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds, e.CellStyle.ForeColor,
                TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left);

            //Draw Sort Icon
            if (grid.SortedColumn?.Index == e.ColumnIndex)
            {
                var sortIcon = grid.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? "▲":"▼";

                //Or draw an icon here.
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, sortIcon,
                    e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds, sortIconColor,
                    TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Right);
            }

            //Prevent Default Paint
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Draw Visual Styles Sort Icon**

To see drawing with Visual Styles sort icon, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53827259/3110834).

Comment: Drawing the column header is the only solution that you can use. The answer is an example, so I just used ▲ and ▼ for sort Icon. You can draw it   simply using `FillPolygon` or `FillPath`. Let me know if you have any problem applying the answer.