# Remove sorting arrow in datagridview header and put the text in the center of the box

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a project which required header text to be in the center, and when click the header it will do the sorting. But the problem is, there is a sorting arrow icon, even when its not showing it push the text to the left.
What i want to achieve is

-removing the sorting arrow and put the text to the center but still keep the sorting function

p/s: i tried handle cell event paint and repaint everything in headercell except for .contentbackground the arrow gone but the text is still pushed to the left. here is the code:

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All &~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

-keep the sorting arrow but always show it

i am working with vb .net but code in c# is fine

how the header is right now

[image: header before click on]

[image: header after click on]

how i want the header to look like

[image]

thank you very much

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: ah yes, my bad, i will add image of what i want it to be right now

Comment: [How to change 'sort glyph icon' color in DataGridView of Windows Form C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47263234/3110834)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For aligning column header text at the middle, you can rely on `DataGridView` properties. But for custom sort icon, you need custom paint.

To set column header text alignment:

- Set `Alignment` property of the `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle` to `MiddleCenter`.

To paint custom sort icon:

- Handle the `CellPainting` event and check if we are painting the header:

  ```
  if (e.RowIndex == -1) //It's header cell
  ```
- Paint cell background

  ```
  e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, false);
  ```
- Paint content foreground (text):

  ```
  e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
  ```
- Paint custom sort glyph using `DrawImage` or by drawing a suitable character:

  ```
  if (grid.SortedColumn?.Index == e.ColumnIndex)
  {
      var sortIcon = grid.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? "▲":"▼";

      //Just for example I rendered a character, you can draw an image.
      TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, sortIcon,
          e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds, sortIconColor,
          TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Right);
  }
  ```
- Stop default paint

  ```
  e.Handled = true;
  ```

**Note - Draw Visual Styles Sort Icon**

- If you wanted to draw default sort icon:

  ```
  e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground);
  ```
- Just as an example, drawing visual style sort icon:

  ```
  if (grid.SortedColumn?.Index == e.ColumnIndex)
  {
      var sortIcon = grid.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ?
          VisualStyleElement.Header.SortArrow.SortedUp : 
          VisualStyleElement.Header.SortArrow.SortedDown;
      var renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(sortIcon);
      var size = renderer.GetPartSize(e.Graphics, ThemeSizeType.Draw);
      renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics,
          new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Right - size.Width,
          e.CellBounds.Top, size.Width, e.CellBounds.Height));
  }
  ```

Comment: very useful information, thank you very much. it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use Header Mouse Click Event and CellPainting Event

VB.NET Code:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    Dim column = DataGridView.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)
    If column.SortMode <> DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable Then
        DataGridView.Sort(column, If(column.SortMode = SortOrder.Ascending, ListSortDirection.Descending, ListSortDirection.Ascending))
    End If
    For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView.Columns
        c.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None
    Next
End Sub
```

Then use painiting for DataGridView

VB.NET Code:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.CellPainting
If e.ColumnIndex = -1 AndAlso e.RowIndex = -1 Then
    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All And Not DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground)
    Dim sortIcon As VisualStyleElement = Nothing
    If DataGridView.SortedColumn IsNot Nothing AndAlso DataGridView.SortOrder <> SortOrder.None Then
        sortIcon = If(DataGridView.SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending, VisualStyleElement.Header.SortArrow.SortedUp, VisualStyleElement.Header.SortArrow.SortedDown)
    Else
        sortIcon = VisualStyleElement.Header.SortArrow.SortedUp
    End If
    If sortIcon IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim renderer As New VisualStyleRenderer(sortIcon)
        Dim size = renderer.GetPartSize(e.Graphics, ThemeSizeType.Draw)
        renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics,
            New Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Right - size.Width,
                          e.CellBounds.Top + ((e.CellBounds.Height - size.Height) \ 2),
                          size.Width,
                          size.Height))
    End If
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

You can also change the color to color of your design, instead of using "White" like in this sample